# How do I correctly close a winform if I have used invoke to update the form from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a winform that subscribes to events from a callback interface. I use...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form  
{ 
    MyTestCallBack _callback;

    public Form1() 
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        //Start otherthread
        API.Create()

        _callback = new MyTestCallBack();
        _callback.MyTestCallBackEvent += callback_MyTestCallBackEvent;
        _callback.OnUpdate(); 
    }

    private callback_MyTestCallBackEvent(MyTestCallBackEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                callback_MyTestCallBackEvent(sender, e);
            }));
            return;
        }
        label1.Text = e.SomeObject.GetDisplayString(); 
    } }

    class MyTestCallBackEventArgs : EventArgs   {
        public SomeObject SomeObj { get; set; }   }

    class MyTestCallBack : Callback   {
        public event EventHandler<MyTestCallBackEventArgs> MyTestCallBackEvent;


    protected virtual void OnMyTestCallBackEvent(MyTestCallBackEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (MyTestCallBackEvent != null)
            MyTestCallBackEvent(this, e); 
    }

    public void OnUpdate(SomeObject someobj) 
    {
        OnMyTestCallBackEvent(new MyTestCallBackEventArgs { SomeObject = someobj }); 
    }  
}
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //tried this but still crashes
        _callback.MyTestCallBackEvent -= callback_MyTestCallBackEvent;
        API.Destroy()
    }
```

When I try to shutdown my form it crashes. "Freezes". I assume it is because of the other thread not shuting down correctly.

How do safely unsubscribe from this event  so that I can close down correctly.

Comment: Seems to me that there's only one thread involved here anyway?  Is `InvokeRequired` actually true when you hit your callback the first time?

Comment: Just checked yes it does come back true. I haven't included but I need to start the other thread using API.Create(). This has the method API.Destroy() to stop.

Comment: I think you need to include those details in your question - they're potentially relevant

Comment: Updated it, my mistake!

Comment: But what are `API.Create()` and `API.Destroy()`?

Comment: API class 

This class provides methods to initialize and destroy theManaged API. 
All programs need to initialize the API before using any functionality. 
At the end of the application, the API should be explicitly destroyed as well. 
All the provided examples show this pattern: 
 Initialise the API and login ( done in one call ) 
 Do something 
 Shutdown the API 
 exit applicationAPI.Create Method  

Creates the Stellar API. Call this before using any other interfaces.

Comment: public static ErrorEnum Create(
 string applicationName,
 string user,
 string password
)

Comment: Destroy the API. Call this before exiting program. 
public static ErrorEnum Destroy().

Comment: Thats all I have in documentation

Comment: After your main form is closed, click the pause button in Visual Studio to see what code is executing. My guess would be your thread is still doing something. If you want your thread to stop when your main form is closed then you have to set its `IsBackground` to true.

Answer (score 1):

To immediately unsubscribe from the event, use:

```
_callback.MyTestCallBackEvent -= callback_MyTestCallBackEvent;
```

Comment: I have done this in the form closing event but it still crashes